# PHP & MySQL - Get variable on URL

Tags: php, mysql, isset

I'm a newbie and need Help.

I've made a page (**page.php**) that shows the list of data from ***MySQL***, but only fetched *6 columns* out of the total *10* columns from my table.

Beside each row, I put a link:

```
<a href="detail.php?id=<?php echo $rows -> num_id;?>" target="_blank">
```

For example, if a *row* with `num_id=8`, the link will be `detail.php?id=8`, which actually works.

The problem is, how can I set **detail.php** page to get the `num_id`?

I have tried using:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{ 

$query2="select * from data_table where num_id=$nokasus ";
$result=mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

while($rows=mysql_fetch_object($result)){ HTML CODE HERE }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the value of `$nokasus`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `select * from data_table where num_id=$_GET['id']` (obviously sanitize before using the value), unless `$nokasus = $_GET['id']` already

Answer (score 0):

how about fetching the id from the url by $_GET[] and assign it to a variable then do your thing.

example:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM data_table WHERE num_id = $id" ;
```

Comment: This is good example until you consider the potential for SQL injection, e.g. what if a visitor passes `detail.php?id=1' or '1=1` or some such mess. It's correct in terms of assigning the variable and referencing it, but consider sanitizing your input before passing it directly into a database.

Answer (score 0):

You might be talking about `GET[]`. Let's also convert your code to ***MySQLi*** instead of predicated ***MySQL***.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("YourHost","YourUsername","YourPassword","YourDatabase");

$id=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['id']); 

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM data_table WHERE num_id='$id'");

while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ HTML CODE HERE }

?>
```